# Can the boundary of $\{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb C^2: \exists z_3 \in \mathbb C,\ |z_1^2 + z_2z_3|<1\}$ be written down explicitly?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can the boundary of $\{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb C^2: \exists z_3 \in \mathbb C,\   |z_1^2 + z_2z_3|<1\}$ be written down explicitly?

Given $(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb C^2 $, I want to find the distance between this point and the boundary of the given set, but I do not know how to write down the boundary explicitly.

Comment: If $z_2$ is non-zero, then $f(z) = z_1^2 + z_2z$ is bijective, so $\{(x,y):y\ne0\}$ is a subset of the given set.

Comment: If $z_2$ is zero, then the allowed values of $z_1$ is the unit ball.

Comment: That is not enough I think since I want to compute the distance as stated in the problem.

Comment: I explicitly showed you what the set contains.